# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'OrderInfo'

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I configured a MultiDataSource in SpringBoot 3.0.5 with Java 17. The Primary data source is working fine, but I'm facing an issue with the Secondary data source.

The findAll() method in the OrderRepository interface is working without any problems, but I keep getting an error in the getOrderInfo() method of OrderQueryDsl. I've been trying to resolve this issue for several days, but I just can't figure out the reason. Please help me out.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableJpaRepositories(
basePackages = "com.demo.solution.invoice.repository.secondary",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManager",
transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager"
)
public class SecondaryDataSourceConfiguration {
private final Environment env;
private final SecondaryDBPropertiesConfig secondaryDBPropertiesConfig;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManager(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.demo.solution.invoice.entity.secondary");
    
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties());
    
        return em;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(secondaryDBPropertiesConfig.getJdbcUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(secondaryDBPropertiesConfig.getAdminID());
        dataSource.setPassword(secondaryDBPropertiesConfig.getAdminPW());
    
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager= new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(secondaryEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    private HashMap<String, String> jpaProperties(){
        HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", secondaryDBPropertiesConfig.getDialect());
        //properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.format_sql"));
    
        return properties;
    
    }

}
```

```
package com.demo.solution.invoice.entity.secondary;
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Getter
@ToString
public class OrderInfo {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private Integer orderId;
@Column(name = "order_no")
private String orderNo;

    @Column(name = "created_time")
    private LocalDateTime createdTime;

}
```

```
package com.demo.solution.invoice.repository.secondary;
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderQueryDsl {
private final JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;
public List\<OrderInfo\> getOrderInfo(){
List\<OrderInfo\> orderInfos = queryFactory
.selectFrom(QOrderInfo.orderInfo)
.fetch();  // error

        return orderInfos;
    }

}
```

```
@Repository  public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository\<OrderInfo, String\> { }
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class OrderQueryDslTest {

    @Autowired
    OrderQueryDsl orderQueryDsl;
    
    @Test
    void getOrders() {
        List<OrderInfo> orderInfos = orderQueryDsl.getOrderInfo();  // error
    }
}
```

[Full Stack Trace]

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'OrderInfo'
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:234)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
at com.demo.solution.invoice.repository.secondary.OrderQueryDsl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getOrderInfo(\<generated\>)
at
```

I've asked ChatGPT everything I could, but its responses were limited to suggesting things like using "@EntityScan" or checking the package location (setPackagesToScan) of the "OrderInfo" class. It mainly focused on confirming if the "@Entity" annotation is applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your Secondary data source not working, first data source was injected at EntityManager.

```
enter code here
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManager(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.demo.solution.invoice.entity.secondary");
    **em.setPersistenceUnitName("secondaryEntityManager");**   // add here
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties());

    return em;
}
```

after setPersistenceUnitName at EntityManager, please make config file.

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "firstEntityManager")
  private EntityManager firstEntityManager;

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "secondaryEntityManager")
  private EntityManager secondEntityManager;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @Qualifier("FirstQF")
  JPAQueryFactory firstQueryFactory() {
    return new JPAQueryFactory(firstEntityManager);
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("SecondQF")
  JPAQueryFactory secondQueryFactory() {
    return new JPAQueryFactory(secondEntityManager);
  }
}
```

you have to make as many EntityManagers and JPAQueryFactory as databases you use.

```
package com.demo.solution.invoice.repository.secondary;

@Repository
public class OrderQueryDsl {

  private final JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;

  // add constructor
  public OrderQueryDsl(@Qualifier("SecondQF") JPAQueryFactory queryFactory) {
    this.queryFactory = queryFactory;
  }

  public List<OrderInfo> getOrderInfo() {
    List<OrderInfo> orderInfos = queryFactory
    .selectFrom(QOrderInfo.orderInfo)
    .fetch();  // error

    return orderInfos;
  }

}
```

and use constructor injection and @Qualifier.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class OrderQueryDslTest {

    @Autowired
    OrderQueryDsl orderQueryDsl;
    
    @Test
    void getOrders() {
        List<OrderInfo> orderInfos = orderQueryDsl.getOrderInfo();  // error
    }
}
```

after all, try it again.